# create PDF in Android

Tags: java, android

I've taken reference of this article for [PDF creation](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-itext-pdf-bluetooth-printer.html), I want to print **first name** and **last name** in PDF. After reference from article I've changed in code and provided my code below.

I'm getting these system error mostly.

1. `java.lang.RuntimeException`: No message found for `the.document.is.not.open`
2. at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfwriter.getdirectcontent(pdfwriter.java:742) in android
   3.at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:73)

Here is my code after changing in original code.

```
        package com.example.pdf;

        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;

        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
        import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
        import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
        import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
        import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
        import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
        import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

            EditText firstName_edt;
            EditText lastName_edt;
            Button preView_btn;
            private BaseFont bfBold;
            private String filepath = "MyInvoices";
            private String filename = "Sample.pdf";
            private File pdfFile;
            private static final String LOG_TAG = "GeneratePDF";

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                /*InputStream license = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.itextkey);
                  LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(license);*/

                firstName_edt = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.activity_main_firstname_edt));

                lastName_edt = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.activity_main_lastname_edt));

                preView_btn = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.activity_main_preview_btn));

                preView_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                            "External Storage not available or you don't have permission to write");
                } else {
                    // path for the PDF file in the external storage
                    pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.activity_main_preview_btn:

                    String firstaName_str = firstName_edt.getText().toString();
                    String lastName_str = lastName_edt.getText().toString();
                    createPdf(firstaName_str, lastName_str);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            private void createPdf(String firstNAME, String lastNAME) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // create file
                try {

                    // create document
                    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 50, 50, 50,
                            50);

                    PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                            new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));

                    PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();

                    document.open();

                    // initialize fonts
                    initializeFonts();

                    // set logo image
                    InputStream input = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                    com.itextpdf.text.Image logo = com.itextpdf.text.Image
                            .getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                    logo.setAbsolutePosition(25, 700);
                    logo.scalePercent(25);
                    document.add(logo);

                    // create paragraph
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Personal Details"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Name:Sachin Singh"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Address: Kolkata"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph("email: ash@gmail.com"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Gender:F"));

                    // set firstname and lastname from edittext
                    createHeadings(cb, 450, 135, firstNAME, lastNAME);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
                String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
                String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            private void initializeFonts() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    bfBold = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD,
                            BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // method for setting firstname and last name
            private void createHeadings(PdfContentByte cb, float x, float y,
                    String firstNAME, String lastNAME) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cb.beginText();
                cb.setFontAndSize(bfBold, 8);
                cb.setTextMatrix(x, y);
                cb.showText(firstNAME.trim());
                cb.showText(lastNAME.trim());
                cb.endText();
            }
        }
```

Xml file

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_firstname_edt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="enter first name"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_lastname_edt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="enter last name"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_preview_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preview" />

    </LinearLayout>

 logcat data

02-18 00:38:10.789: I/eFrame(32423): pkgname_before:com.example.pdf  class:com.android.launcher2.Launcher
02-18 00:39:45.171: I/eFrame(32423): pkgname_before:com.sec.android.app.launcher  class:com.example.pdf.MainActivity
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410): com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: No message found for 1.not.found.as.resource
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Type1Font.<init>(Type1Font.java:192)
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:699)
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:622)
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:457)
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.initializeFonts(MainActivity.java:162)
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.createPdf(MainActivity.java:101)
02-18 00:39:53.159: W/System.err(32410):    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
02-18 00:39:53.169: W/System.err(32410):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSimple(PdfWriter.java:2280)
02-18 00:39:53.169: W/System.err(32410):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(PdfContentByte.java:1704)
02-18 00:39:53.169: W/System.err(32410):    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.createHeadings(MainActivity.java:137)
02-18 00:39:53.169: W/System.err(32410):    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.createPdf(MainActivity.java:119)
02-18 00:39:53.169: W/System.err(32410):    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
```

Comment: please point out the lines where the errors will come...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs at line 94 ..when call fror createpdf method..

Comment: can You please post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i am very new to Android..how to post stack trace ..please help me..

Comment: are You developing in eclipse? If yes, there is a window with some tabs below Your coding window. In that, there must be LogCat. You can select different message types. Use "error" and reproduce the issue. The copy paste that stuff....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs logcat speed is  too fast ..and also i am trying to filter app name wise bt not filtering messages app name wise..unable to copy paste those messages..

Comment: clean the logcat short before You reproduce Your issue. Than reproduce it and select "error". That works, then mark the lines with the error and paste it.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs hey i edited my question as per your suggestion..and i optimized this by Laurent YHUEL suggestion below...

Comment: which code is in line 137 in Your main activity?

Answer (score 0):

Call method "document.open() before call method "docWriter.getDirectContent()":

```
document.open();

PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
```

Regarding your font exception, I don't use BaseFont. Please try this:

```
// colors
    private static final BaseColor colorFont = new BaseColor(51, 51, 51);
    private static final BaseColor colorBlue = new BaseColor(32, 119, 215);

        // fonts
        private static final Font fontDefault = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10,
                Font.NORMAL, colorFont);
        private static final Font fontBold = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10,
                Font.BOLD, colorFont);
        private static final Font fontTitle = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10,
                Font.BOLD, colorBlue);

    new Paragraph(new Chunk("Personal Details",
                        fontDefault))
```

Comment: ...thnx,,,i tried ur suggestion ..some errors were removed...but still not working,,,i edited my post with logcat print...

Comment: @user3519331 I edit my answer regarding your font issue

Comment: @user3519331, Is it useful ?